# Preprocess a views template

Tags: views, commerce, theming

I Have a template in my `cart_template` module called `views-view-table--commerce-cart-form.tpl`. Is there a way to create a preprocess function for that template.

What I have tried : `hook_preprocess(&variables, $hook)`, but doing `dpm($hook)` display a lot of weird names like : block, page, views_view ... etc. which doesn't indicate when the function gets called for my template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, every .tpl.php file has an equivalent preprocess function for it.  And, in general, the preprocess function and template files have the same name (in the Drupal sense).

The function you want is [`template_preprocess_views_view_table()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_table/7).  You can place this in a module, or in your theme.  Just name it accordingly.

Look at the default preprocess function for how the `$view` gets pulled out and/or `dpm($variables['view'])`.  You will likely need to examine it to limit the function to just the view/display you need.

You can also try implementing `MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_table__commerce_cart_form()` to limit to just that instantiation, but I don't recall if the Views module will do this.

The [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module can also help out tracking down what preprocess functions get called for each .tpl.php file.

Comment: for the first function I get `Cannot redeclare template_preprocess_views_view_table()` and using the Theme Developer modules I get only the name of the preprocess in use not thoses I can implement

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira You need to name the function to match the module or theme you are putting it in.  For example, if the module is mymodule, then it would be  `mymodule_preprocess_views_view_table()`

Comment: Thanks that worked and I got the view name at $vars['view']['name']